# Using Core Data in code - Objective-C/Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, entity, nsarraycontroller

I have Core Data entity named `Event` in my `xcdatamodeld` with 2 attributes : `title` and `date`. I have also an `arrayController` set to Entity mode with the `Event` entity (done with interface builder). I want to access the attributes of the objects in the `arrayController` using code. How can I do that?

Comment: You can try reading the [Core Data code snippets](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008285) documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arrayController.arrangedObjects[index].title = newValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other posters about looking into some of the docs on core data. 
The Big Nerd Ranch books are a really great starting point if you find the online documentation overwhelming (it comes in time).

Select your `Event` entity in your `xcdatamodel`, then from the menu do:
`Editor > Create NSManaagedObject Subclass`

Then you can do:
`Event *event = [arrayController.arrangedObjects[index]];`
`event.title = newValue or [event setTitle];`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest starting with the Apple tutorial, [Core Data Tutorial for iPhone OS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html), then moving on to one of the sample apps, such as [CoreDataBooks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html).  Core Data is not an easy technology to master, so expect this to take some time.